# How to query with greaterThan for an embedded document using Spring Data MongoDB Repository?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

**Member.class**

```
@Document(collection = "alfagift_member")
public class Member {

    @Field(value = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Field(value = "member_id")
    private String memberId;

    @Field(value = "pin")
    private Pin pin;
}
```

**Pin.class**

```
public class Pin {

    @Field(value = "encrypted_value")
    private String encryptedValue;
    
    @Field(value = "last_blocked")
    private Date lastBlocked;
}
```

**MemberRepository.class**

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends MongoRepository<Member, String> {

  @Query(value="{'member_id' : ?0}, {'pin.last_blocked' : ?1}")
  Member findByMemberIdAndLastBlockedGreaterThan(Integer memberId, Date now);
}
```

> **Then I tried to make a query method like this, but the function of greaterthan itself doesn't work**

I was confused, how to solve it ??

** **EDITT**

**Data in MongoDB**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f1fa9876b911d2b27d0bcf5"),
  "full_name": "this is my name",
  "pin": {
    "encrypted_value": "e9b0d0aae93291679b304f9d3c058029fa4253ccaf366cae3aeb473099b7aff8:qcfq9josgstqjcoun0isnvmja3",
    "last_blocked": ISODate("2020-08-03T05:00:31.597Z")
  },
  "member_id": 2200146,
  "_class": "id.alfadigital.alfagift.service.account.v1.db.mongo.domain.Member"
}
```

And parameter sending

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1));
Member member = memberRepository.findByMemberIdAndLastBlockedGreaterThan(memberId, now);
```

Comment: Have you tried this @Query(" {'member_id : ?0 '} ,{'pin.last_blocked': { $gt : ?1}}")

Comment: I have tried but the results are still the same @VishalPawar

Comment: can you what are you sending date parameter and what database has?

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the `@Query` and using `AndPinLastBlockedGreaterThan`?

Comment: I have edited the document, you can see **EDITT @VishalPawar

Comment: that works dude .. thanks man :) @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Comment: `@Query` is needed sometimes, but it shouldn't be your first attempt; Spring Data is pretty good about being able to analyze the requested query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Update the repository like this

```
    @Repository
    public interface MemberRepository 
                             extends MongoRepository<Member, String> {

   
        Member findByMemberIdAndPinLastBlockedGreaterThan(Integer memId, 
                                                          Date now);
    }
```

- You are deducting one hour from current time and your stored document has blocked time before that.  For testing purpose, reduct 5 hours and query.

```
   Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(5));
```